# how to redirect users to a custom page when they click on their display name or nickname?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

How to redirect users to a custom page when they click on their display name or my profile or dashboard on my WordPress site. Because I locked `/wp-admin` with this

```
add_action('admin_init', 'no_mo_dashboard');
function no_mo_dashboard() {
global $wp_query;
if (!current_user_can('manage_options') && $_SERVER['DOING_AJAX'] != '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php') {
$wp_query->set_404();
status_header( 404 );
get_template_part( 404 ); exit();
}
}
```

and an user gets 404 error if requests `mydoimain/wp-admin`. But the problem is when an user clicks on his display name it returns 404 error. So in nutshell what I want is that when an user request for `mydomain/wp-admin` should get 404 but when the user clicks on his display name or "my profile" or dashboard gets redirected any custom page on front-end. Anyone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using jQuery you can do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#display_name_button_id').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        window.location = 'link-to-custom-page.html';
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am a newbie to Wordpress. Can u please tell me where to put that code. I mean in which file.

Comment: Shall I put it in theme's function.php

Comment: and in place of that 'link-to-custom-page.html' shall i put my custom page url. Please reply it would be great help.

Comment: yes you should put your custom page url in place of "link-to-custom-page.html" and there should be a file called header.php in your theme where you can add the code wrapped up in <script> tags

Comment: `<$('#display_name_button_id').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    window.location = 'http://mdomain.com/mprofile';
});>` I put it in header.php like this. But didn't work please help.

Comment: I put it at the bottom I mean at the end of the file.

Comment: I've edited my question so it has script tags have a look. Also you can have a look at this tutorial http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-the-enqueue-script-for-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/ to learn how to add scripts to WordPress